# regular expression and a word list Java

Tags: java, regex, file

I have to ask the user for a certain pattern for the words that want to retrieve 
for example if the user enters

#5: means an English word of size 5

#4=at: means an English word of length four and contains the substring at. That includes chat,
rate, ..

#6-^^y: means an English word of length six and it ends with the substring of two vowels
followed by the letter ‘y’

#5+*ro: means an English word of length five and it starts with the substring having a non-
vowel letter followed by the substring ‘ro’. This includes broke, froze, wrote, ..

I handled the file part correctly but couldn't do the regular expression part

The is my code

```
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class ReplaceApp {

    public static void main (String args[])
    {


    ReplaceApp rf = new ReplaceApp();
    Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);
    String pattern;

    rf.openFile();
    rf.readData();

    System.out.println("Enter the pattern that you wish to retrieve words of");
    System.out.println("If you want help type \"?\"");
    pattern=in.nextLine();
    if (pattern.equals("?"))
    {
        System.out.println("- The symbol * can only be replaced by a none vowel letter");
        System.out.println("- The symbol ^ can only be replaced by a vowel letter");
        System.out.println("- The symbol & can only be replaced by a vowel or none vowel letter");
        System.out.println("- A special pattern that starts with # followed by an integer and can be followed by a positive, "
                + "negative or equal sign followed by a pattern as explained earlier means an English word of the length "
                + "specified after # and contains the described pattern as substring of it. The substring is at the "
                + "beginning of the word if the sign is positive, at the end of the word if the sign is negative, and "
                + "anywhere if the sign is equals.");
    }

    if (pattern.startsWith("*"))
    {
        System.out.println(rf.retrieveWords("^[b|c|d|f|g|h|j|k|l|m|n|p|q|r|s|t|v|w|x|y|z]"));
    }
    if (pattern.startsWith("^"))
    {
        System.out.println(rf.retrieveWords("^[aeuio]"));
    }

    }

     Scanner input;
     ArrayList<String> wordList=new ArrayList<String>();;

    public void openFile() {
        try {
            input = new Scanner(new File("words.txt"));
        } // end try
        catch (FileNotFoundException fileNotFoundException) {
            System.out.println("Error opening file.");
        } // end catch

    } // end method openFile

    public void readData() {

        // read records from file using Scanner object
        while (input.hasNext()) {
            wordList.add(input.nextLine());
        } // end while

        input.close();

    } // end method readRecords

    public Object[] retrieveWords(String re)
    {
        ArrayList<String> wordsToFind=new ArrayList<String>(); 

        for(String word:wordList){ 
        if(word.matches(re)) 
            wordsToFind.add(word); 
        } 

        return wordsToFind.toArray();
    }
}
```

Comment: what about a pattern that the user enters

Comment: It sounds like you are defining your own pattern language. Is there a particular reason you are doing this instead of using standard regex syntax?

Comment: @user3590565 you have to translate user pattern to standard regex pattern

Comment: Visit on [online visual regex tester](https://www.debuggex.com) to create/test you regex.

Comment: @merlin2011 I guess. But I don't know how to do it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is some of the regex patterns

```
#5: means an English word of size 5
```

`\b\w{5}\b`

---

```
#4=at: means an English word of length four and contains 
the substring at. That includes chat, rate, ..
```

`\bat\w{2}\b|\b\wat\w\b|\b\w{2}at\b`

---

```
#6-^^y: means an English word of length six and it ends with 
the substring of two vowels followed by the letter ‘y’
```

`\b\w{3}[aeiou]{2}y\b`

---

```
#5+*ro: means an English word of length five and it starts with 
the substring having a non- vowel letter followed by the substring ‘ro’. 
This includes broke, froze, wrote, ..
```

`\b[^aeiou]ro\w{2}\b`

---

Pattern explanation

```
\b             A word boundary

\w             A word character: [a-zA-Z_0-9]

X{n}           X, exactly n times

[abc]          a, b, or c (simple class)

[^abc]         Any character except a, b, or c (negation)
```

Study [Java Regex Pattern](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/regex/Pattern.html) for detained explanation of each pattern.

Comment: Your first one needs to be `\b\w{5}\b` to match only 5 letter words.

Comment: But `\b` ignores punctuation. (The OP is pretty vague about the source of his words -- it could be a word list, or it could be real-world text.)

Comment: but what i am asking if the user enters his pattern

Comment: What do you mean by user pattern? Does user know java regex pattern? Why don't you make some rules for user and in the background convert it into java regex.

Comment: **There is no in-build regex pattern as per your user pattern**

Comment: @user3590565 regex are hard for some programmers and you want to let users put a pattern? It's better if you create something similar and easy and convert it